# HP Smart Array - Swapping drives in RAID set to upgrade

Tags: raid, hp, hp-smart-array

I have a HP DL360 G7, with Smart Array controller that has 2x RAID sets (RAID 10). Host OS is VMWare ESX. The 2nd RAID set has 4x 10k 600GB Midline drives that are to be upgrade to 15k 600GB Enterprise drives. In the old days I would have just pulled the old drive out, waiting a moment, then put the new one in, waited for the array to rebuild onto the new drive and repeated the steps. That was in the days of G1-G2 servers with much older controllers, plus I had Windows as the host with the Smart Array utility.

What I am hoping to avoid is shutting down the VMs, copying them, then having to restart the server to go into the RAID utility. I would like to confirm since the only difference in drives will be the RPM speed, these could be swapped sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this should work fine, it'll take a while but yes.